# Is it possible to construct an object partially with Spring DI and partially with Jersey DI?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have a class JerseyWebService  which uses Jersey DI to inject dependency

```
@Path("/baskets")
public class JerseyWebService {
    @Inject
    ExternalApiServiceInterface api;
    ...
}
```

The dependency is specified in the binder

```
public class CustomBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {   
       bind(ExternalApiService.class).to(ExternalApiServiceInterface.class);
       ...
    }
```

But the problem here is that `ExternalApiService` has other dependencies and it uses Spring to inject them.

```
class ExternalApiService implements ExternalApiServiceInterface{
    @Autowired
    AnotherService aservice;
```

Is it possible to specify only some dependencies in binder which Jersey will Inject and other dependencies being injected by Spring ?

If not ,then if had been `@Inject` instead of `@Autowired` in `ExternalApiService` would it be mandatory to specify all bindings in the binder class?

Does Jersey DI has no Autowiring like feature or delegate injecting a dependency to Spring if it can't find any binding?

Comment: If you're using a fairly recent version of Jersey 2, simply adding the jersey-spring3 library to your application should allow Jersey to dependency inject your Spring beans without the need for custom binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It should work](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-hk2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/underdog/jersey/spring/hk2/service/Hk2ServiceImpl.java). Given you have the required Spring-Jersey integration dependency<sup>[**1**]</sup> and have correctly configured the application<sup>[**2**]</sup>

<sub>1. [See Spring DI support in Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html)</sub>
<sub>2. [See official Jersey Spring example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp)</sub>

What happens is [HK2](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/) (Jersey's DI framework) will look for an [`InjectionResolver`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html#d0e16663) for the `@Autowired` annotation, in order to resolve the dependency. The `jersey-spring3` dependency has the [`AutowiredInjectionResolver`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/spring3/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/AutowiredInjectResolver.java), which holds a reference to Spring's `ApplicationContext`. From there it's just matter of looking it up in the application context, to resolve the dependency.